# Leak: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected although I call .release

Tags: java, networking, netty

Somtimes this error appears although I call .release() can anyone explain this ?

Thanks in advance

Here is my Code

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    try {


        if (in != null) {
               port = parseProxyline(in.copy());//According to the error log here occurs the leak 

            if (port != 0) {
                new ProxyRemoteConn(port, in.copy(), ctx);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        in.release();
    }


}
```

And the error msg

```
LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:402)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
    io.netty.buffer.UnsafeByteBufUtil.copy(UnsafeByteBufUtil.java:436)
    io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.copy(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:216)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.copy(AbstractByteBuf.java:1194)
    ProxyOutgoingChannelHandler.channelRead(ProxyOutgoingChannelHandler.java:50)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
    io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

This code is to read a port in an added line inside the header and then open a new connection to it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you call [ByteBuff.copy()](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#copy--), you're creating a new ByteBuff instance, which must also be released.